# How do I decode IEnumerable<Person> passed from controller via AJAX to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleByUserIdAndYear(int userId, int year)
    {
        return DataProvider.GetPeople(userId, year).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Javascript :

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPeopleByUserIdAndYear", "Controller")',
            data: { userId: uId, year:selectedYear },
            success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                debugger;
                //How do I assign the data variable to a javascript array of some sorts?
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

So my question is. The IEnumerable that is returned to the data variable I need to assign to a javascript array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you well...
if you get `JSON` in response then use `var someVar = JSON.parse(data)`.
if `data` is already serialized array, then just use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your success block of AJAX:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    persons.push(data[i]);
}
```

where `persons` is an array.